# how to have multiple tables included in summarize function - Reporting builder

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, dax, reportbuilder, power-bi-report-server

I need to build a paginated report (matrix) where I only display in the column group the top 12 City Area by Net sales.  In order to include the ranking I need to have Addcolumns and Summarize functions (Ranking doesn't work with summarizecolumns).
the report will look like the following pic:
[image]

But Summarize function doesn't allow columns from other tables and I need to have the business units in there, I've been trying for days to figure this out :( any help would be very appreciated!
this is my code so far:

```
Define 
VAR _Version="01"
VAR _Country ="United States"

EVALUATE 
    ADDCOLUMNS(SUMMARIZE(
        'Dim - CostCenter'[Country],
        'Dim - Period'[Period Date],
        'Dim - Flow'[Flow],
         'Dim - CostCenter'[Stores],
        'Dim - Reporting Unit'[Business Unit], 
        'Dim - Reporting Unit'[Sort_image], 
        FILTER(VALUES('Dim - Period'[Version]), ('Dim - Period'[Version] = _Version)), 
        FILTER(VALUES('Dim - Flow'[Flow Code]), ('Dim - Flow'[Flow Code] = _Flow)), 
        "Net Sales", [Net Sales]
    ),
  "Ranking", RANKX(ALLSELECTED('Dim - CostCenter'[City Area]), [Net Sales],,0))
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks David but Ranking doesn't work inside summarizecolumns but I ended up breaking the code in half, on the first one I do summarizecolumns and on the second one I do addcolumns and I add the ranking. that solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

> Summarize function doesn't allow columns from other tables

Try with the newer [SUMMARIZECOLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarizecolumns-function-dax) instead.  See [Introducing SUMMARIZECOLUMNS](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-summarizecolumns/)